# Google map not working on web?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing problem related to Google map. First time when page load It show google map but If I re-lode page again google map not shown on page.Any body have Idea about this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code..

Comment: '<script>
        function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
            var map = new         google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 13,
                center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map
            });
        }
    </script><script async="" defer="" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDZIsoEOiEWycHlbAjjsuNtI4r_WRfgTRg&amp;callback=initMap">
    </script>'

Comment: Please add the code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this way :

```
<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px;background:yellow"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>
<script>
function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
        zoom: 10,
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
```